# Prepared statement database connection must be instansiated first?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

The parts in bold are what I am questioning. Inside the `search_for_new_user` function, if I change `$conn->prepare` to `$this->db_connection()->prepare`. I receive a lost connection error. However in the function right above it `db_conn_test` I can use this syntax. In both cases I am returning the `$connection` so I don't understand why there must be a difference in syntax.

```
class Database {

    function db_connection() {
        $server = "localhost";
        $user = "user";
        $password = "password";
        $database = "database";

        return $connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
    }

    function db_conn_test() {
        if (**$this->db_connection()->connect_errno**) {
            die($this->db_connection()->connect_errno . ": " . $this->db_connection()->connect_error);
        } else {
            echo "connected to mysql database";
        }
    }

    function search_for_new_user($email) {
        **$conn = $this->db_connection();**
        if ($stmt = **$conn->prepare**("SELECT email FROM users where email = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($result);
            $stmt->fetch();
            echo $result;
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `db_conn_test` you call `db_connection` twice only if you got connection error during first `db_connection` call, so in this case connection to DB is **not created**.

But in `search_for_new_user` you create connection twice.

I.e.:
in `db_conn_test`:

```
// if connection not created, because you got error
if ($this->db_connection()->connect_errno) {
    // therefore each time you call db_connection(), 
    // you again try create connection, and got same error
    // and return it in die text
    die($this->db_connection()->connect_errno . ": " . $this->db_connection()->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "connected to mysql database";
}
```

but in `search_for_new_user`: you call `db_connection()` and create connection(if all is ok). And then if you call `db_connection` in second try, first connection is gone away and you got error.

Your class should looks like this:

```
class Database {
    protected $connection;

    function db_connection() {
        if ($this->connection !== null) {
            return $this->connection;
        }

        $server = "localhost";
        $user = "user";
        $password = "password";
        $database = "database";

        return $this->connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
    }
}
```